# how to add a common border effect with curved radius to the boundaries of two adjacent sections using css?

Tags: html, css

[how to add a common border to the two adjacent sections with left border radius being curved upside and right being downside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibi7K.png)

This is what im trying to acheive but im unable to do so:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQY3C.png)

heres what im doing in the first about section:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxVQ9.png

heres what im getting after doing so:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/45m1X.png

Comment: Hi Tanish, welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Show us a [reprex].

Comment: Pictures of code does not constitute code, copy and paste enough of the relevant code into the question as text, formatted as code. Please see the "*[ask]*" guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be with pseudo CSS `::before`, and you need comb them together with their positions (`right` & `top`), like so:

```css
#about {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
#about {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 200px;
  border-bottom: 10px dotted rgb(39, 50, 80);
}

/*new code from here: */
#about:before {
  content: "";
  border-top-right-radius: 200px;
  border-top: 10px dotted rgb(39, 50, 80);
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  /* you can tweak around with these: */
  top: 408px;
  right: -292px;
}
```

```html
<div id="about">
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

...or apply the same to the following sibling of the "about".